# restarting nic with phpseclib hangs the whole apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, phpseclib, network-interface

I have struggled for 2 weeks for this problem, I use phpseclib to send commands from the web to the router to perform different behaviours, one of them is to restart the network interface of the router, I am good to restart the network interface, but after running the command, the whole apache freezes, and does not response to any other http request, I am using phpseclib 0.3.5. Thanks very much for the help first

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
  ajax work here to call the runCMDAdvance function and with timeout specified
});
```

PHP

```
//function to run the command
function runCMDAdvance($sshIP, $cmd, $tVal,$tarIP){
        $ssh = new Net_SSH2($sshIP,$this->port);
        if (!$ssh->login($this->username, $this->password)){
            echo "Bad Login";
            return false;
        }
        //set timeout for running ssh command, should be done after the ssh object has been initialized
        $tVal>0 ? $ssh->setTimeout($tVal):"";

                        $res = $ssh->exec($cmd);
            $ssh->disconnect();
            return $res;
}

$cmd =  INCL_PATH . ' && ' . '/sbin/uci commit network && '.'/sbin/uci commit dhcp && '.'/etc/init.d/network restart 2>&1 && exit'."\n";

            $res = $ssh2_conn->runCMDAdvance($ip, $cmd, 20, "");
```

My guess is that when the restart network interface is executed, the AP disconnects and somehow crash the phpseclib, but I have no idea on how to solve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update:
I just did an experiment, whenever I run the above ssh command, the web server takes 15.3 minutes to handle another request...
http://i102.photobucket.com/albums/m112/ihmcjacky/Mobile%20Uploads/000_zpscc73f7f0.jpg

Comment: If the network interface is being restarted then the `setTimeout` call won't do anything since, at that point, phpseclib would have lost it's own connection and it's phpseclib that's checking to see how much time has elapsed - not the server. Really, I think the problem here is that you're restarting the nic. It sounds like every other command - save for this one - works?

Answer (score 0):

To neubert: Thanks for the feedback, actually majority of the commands are running well using the phpseclib.

Referring to the server unresponsive, if it is unavoidable, can I shorten the "dead period" of the server hang? Or any other workable solutions on this?